# редактирование xml файла в c#

Tags: c#, xml

вот есть у меня список в xml файле, я по нему прохожусь и вывожу в textbox, но что если нужно добавить/удалить элемент в xml файле? как через код это можно сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <list>item1</list>
  <list>item2</list>
  <list>item3</list>
</root>
```

xml файл считываю так

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("list.xml");
```

Comment: 1. Считать файл 2. Изменить данные 3. Записать в файл

Comment: @tym32167 ты не понял, мне нужно в xml файле добавить строчку <list>new item</list> или наоборот удалить одну из существующих строчек. я понимаю, что надо через какой-нибудь innerText в файле, но не знаю какой и куда обращаться

Comment: Мне просто непонятно как ты хочешь добавлять/удалять. Тебе надо отдельный интерфейс для этого, чтобы юзеры могли редактировать файл? Или ты хочешь просто по тихому считать и поправить? Или это какие то настройки, что ты хочешь считывать при запуске приложения и сохранять при закрытии?

Comment: Например, если ты считываешь xml через десериализацию в объект, то ты можешь этот объект изменить и сериализовать обратно в файл

Comment: @tym32167 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.Load("list.xml"); а дальше с foreach прохожусь по всем элементам и вытаскиваю их innerText значения

Comment: Добавь этот код в вопрос, чтобы всем было понятно, как ты считываешь

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Изменить XML файл можно так:

```
// Считать файл
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("My file name");

// Получить первый элемент
var node = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];

// удалить его
doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(node);


// создать новый элемент
var newNode = doc.CreateElement("list");
newNode.InnerText = "item4";

// добавить новый элемент
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);

// Сохранить в файл
doc.Save("my file name");
```

Comment: спасибо. сработало. а как удалить уже существующий элемент?

Comment: @epsilon обновил ответ