# Изменить данные XML файла

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, файлы

Нужно из xml файла получать данные, по нажатию кнопки менять значение на 2 (+2). А вот как изменять данные из файла найти не могу нормально.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<plan>
  <day1>
    <pushUps>14</pushUps>
    <pullUps>7</pullUps>
    <pullUpsBar>3</pullUpsBar>
  </day1>
</plan>
```

Comment: Погуглите в сторону LINQ to XML. Довольно простая в освоении и эффективная штука.

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [редактирование xml файла в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726229/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-xml-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Вам в любом случае придется перезаписать файл целиком. Так что вычитывайте его в память любым удобным/известным способом, меняйте значения и записывайте обратно или в новый файл.

Comment: Распишите чуть подробнее: как я понимаю, вы делаете некий учёт упражнений. Может, внутри тэга `plan` имеет смысл создать тэг, хранящий коллекцию однотипных экземпляров `day`?

Comment: [XMLSerialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) тоже может пригодиться вам :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно парсить xml и менять значения, подробнее [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726229/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c).

Если же необходимо работать с большим количеством данных, то можно использовать сериализацию. Для начала на сайте нужно получить версию ваших данных в виде программных сущностный языка C#. Для этого можно воспользоваться этим сайтом [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) (или аналогом); классы можно описать и самому.

Получиться что-то на подобие такого:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="day1")]
public class Day1 {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="pushUps")]
    public string PushUps { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="pullUps")]
    public string PullUps { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="pullUpsBar")]
    public string PullUpsBar { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="plan")]
public class Plan {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="day1")]
    public Day1 Day1 { get; set; }
}
```

Тип `string` можно поменять, например, на `int`.

Сериализация и десериализация:

```
Plan plan;
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Plan));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    plan = (Plan)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}

plan.Day1.PullUps += 2;
plan.Day1.PullUpsBar += 2;
plan.Day1.PushUps += 2;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, plan);
}
```