# Запись и считывание XML файла

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Подскажите, у меня есть форма с textbox'ами, как мне записать данные с них в XML файл, и потом считать данные с файла в один отдельный textbox строкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [редактирование xml файла в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726262/179763) ?

Comment: в блоке catch и за ним отсутствует return. Таким образом в случае выброса исключения нет точки выхода из метода. А вообще пустой блок catch да еще и без указания конкретного класса отлавливаемых исключений - очень плохая практика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вам следует использовать отдельный класс, для хранения значений textBox'ов.

```
[Serializable] // это нам пригодится для дальнейшей сериализации
public class DataStrings
{
 public string String1 {get;set;} // для textBox1.Text
 public string String2 {get;set;} //для textBox2.Text
}
```

Экземпляр класс DataString теперь можно использовать для сериализации в Xml.
Пример метода сериализации:

```
public void SerializeThis(object obj, string path)
{
  XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
  using(var fs = new FileStream("Example.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
    formatter.Serialize(fs, obj);
  }
}
```

Теперь Вы можете подумать о десериализации данных из файла, пример:

```
public DataStrings DeserializeThis(string path)
{
  XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataStrings));
  using(var fs = new FileStream("Example.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
     DataStrings result = (DataStrings)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Имея экземпляр класса DataStrings, вы можете использовать его свойства для отображения данных в Ваших textBox'ах. Пример использования:

```
var exmpl = new DataStrings(){String1 = textBox1.Text, String2 = textBox2.Text};
SerializeThis(exmpl, "Example.xml");
var exmpl_des = DeserializeThis("Example.xml");
textBox1.Text = exmpl_des.String1;
textBox2.Text = exmpl_des.String2;
```

Для использования классов и атрибута из примера требуется использовать пространство имен System.Xml.Serialization;

Comment: Спасибо, только в методе public DataStrings DeserializeThis(string path) вылетает "не все ветви кода возвращают значения", я пока далекий от этого но вроде все также сделал. В вопросе добавил скриншот с сообщением

Comment: Если вы используете конструкцию try{}catch{}, в блоке catch тоже нужно что-то вернуть. Это может быть new DataStrings, ну либо бросить исключение throw new Exception("ТЕКСТ_ВАШЕГО_ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ"). Блок catch принято оформлять следующим образом - catch(Excepion ex){} и уже внутри что-то предпринимать, исходя из ex -> Console.Write(ex.Message) или throw ex, или еще куча вариантов :)

Comment: Точно, спасибо Вам за помощь)