# Чтение и замена в файле XML на C#

Tags: c#, xml

Понимаю вопрос от слова совсем нет. Помогите.
Есть простой файл XML:

```
<Day>
  <name>Олег</name>
</Day>
```

Как прочитать данный файл в C# и имя "Олег" заменить на любое другое?

Спасибо!

Мне предложили ссылку, где я могу удалять первый нод и закрыли тему, но это не решение проблемы, а если я не знаю номер строки и т.п.
Поэтому вопрос актуален, мне нужно конкретно найти нод  и заменить содержимое, это будет текст, на другое, по факту да удалить и записать новое, но конкретно в этом ноде.

Yitzhak Khabinsky, именно это мне и нужно, но твой код не работает у меня. Видимо что то я делаю не так.
Yitzhak Khabinsky, беру слова обратно, всё топ. Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726229/179763

Comment: Я вам рекомендую использовать JSON так как он быстрее, проще и удобнее

Comment: @Lofectr у XML есть свои преимущества и у автора элементарно может не быть выбора

Comment: @YegorAndrosov какие же преимущества?

Comment: @Lofectr XSD и DTD, как мне кажется, развиты намного сильнее, чем аналоги в JSON'e

Comment: Ребят, нужен именно XML, за ссылки тоже спасибо, но там нет того что мне нужно, либо такому гению как я нужно серьезнее разъяснить, раз я не вижу. Спасибо!

Comment: Хорошая ссылка по теме: https://www.yegor256.com/2015/11/16/json-vs-xml.html

Comment: @Velen, LINQ to XML доступен уже с 2007 года, то есть 13 лет. Ссылка, которую вам предложили, использует более старый API и не предоставляет прямого решения для ваших нужд.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky дело говоришь, в итоге мне необходимо менять не строки, а атрибуты, быстро скинуть с себя вопрос не удалось, пришлось почитать побольше, но в целом всё очень просто.

Comment: @Velen, Пожалуйста, свяжитесь со мной в LinkedIn.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky, как Вас найти?

Answer (score 1):

Используя LINQ to XML.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputFileName = @"e:\temp\input.xml";
    const string outputFileName = @"e:\temp\output.xml";
    
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputFileName);
        
    XElement xElem = xdoc.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault();
    xElem.SetValue("Петр");
    
    xdoc.Save(outputFileName);
}
```